# No progress report display

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

The progress report display has disappeared from my Kindle Paperwhite screen. I have tried tapping on the bottom left corner of the screen, as suggested in other posts, but it just turns the page. Is there any other way of re-starting the progress report display?

Answer (score 1):

Open the top bar, as if to go back to the home page from within your book.

Tap Page Display menu, then select Font & Page Settings. You can control the progress from the reading tab of the dialog that will come up.